# How can we use the AWS lambda "event" (API Gateway) as a Readable stream?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to send a file in a *POST* request to the *AWS lambda* and get a result after some processing. I want to use the request body as a readable stream as explained in the example below.

```
// AWS lambda (using the serverless framework)
module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {
    // pipe the request content to another stream (.pipe())
}
```

I can do the same in *Express* easily, but unable to use the *event* object provided by AWS lambda.

```
// Express server
app.post('/endpoint', (req, res) => {
    req.pipe(anotherStream)
})
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use pipe in Lambda because API Gateway will only give you `event` as an object.

Comment: @dashmug I am trying to send the uploaded content (a file) to a different API for some processing.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda is intended to process distinct events (given as an object) from AWS Api Gateway (or any other Lambda invocation). What you could do instead:

1. Use web sockets with AWS Lambda to handle streams by having subsequent Lambda invocation for data sent via an open socket

   - [Working with WebSocket APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-websocket-api.html)
2. Expose AWS S3 operations (e.g. PUT in your case) via AWS Api Gateway, and trigger a Lambda after the upload is complete using S3 events

   - [Expose API Methods to Access an Amazon S3 Object in a Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html#api-items-in-folder-as-s3-objects-in-bucket)
   - [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)